# Meaning of Inverse Functions Structure

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given $f(x) =\frac{x+6}{2}$

Find the Inverse Function

$f(x) =\frac{x+6}{2} \Rightarrow y =\frac{x+6}{2}$

$x =\frac{y+6}{2}$  <= Interchange the $x$ and $y$ and Solve for $y$

$y = 2x-6 $

My question: Can someone please explain why we interchange the $x$ and $y$ and then solve for $y$.

I know those are the steps to compute the inverse of the function but I don't understand the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y = f(x) = \frac{x+6}{2}$. Given a value of $x$ we know how to obtain $y$ by just plugging in the value of $x$. What the inverse function does, is it allows us to obtain $y$ given $x$. Notice for this particular function if we solve for $x$, we get:

$$y = \frac{x+6}{2} \iff x=2y-6.$$

Notice now that if we are given $y$, we can now easily obtain $x$ by using the formula $x=2y-6$, thus the inverse function is,
$$x = f^{-1}(y) = 2y-6.$$

However, when we have a *function*, the symbol we use for the variable that we use inside the function doesn't matter, it's simply a placeholder. If we wanted to, we could use $x$ or $m$ or $☺$ as our variable, thus the function $f^{-1}(☺) = 2☺-6$ is the same function as the previous one. Typically, we use $x$ as the variable for a function, so we write,
$$f^{-1}(x) = 2x-6.$$