# Inverse Function: $F = \frac{9}{5}C + 32$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the Inverse function for: $F = \frac{9}{5}C + 32$
The inverse function is usually obtain by interchanging the variables and solving the equation.

But for $F = \frac{9}{5}C + 32$ the inverse is found by solving for $C$.

Why are we not allow to interchange the variables $F$ and $C$ and then just solve for $C$?

Comment: See the just asked (and answered) [Meaning of Inverse Functions Structure](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925944/meaning-of-inverse-functions-structure). For arbitrary functions $f(x)$ the naming of the variable is just a convention, and it's customary to name it $x$. Here however the names of the variables have to do with *Celsius* and *Fahrenheit* i.e. they are meaningful so you want to preserve them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to interchange variables and solve for $F$ in this case, not $C$. That is,
$$
F = (9/5)C + 32 \to C = (9/5)F + 32 \\
F = (5/9)(C - 32).
$$
Only in this case it looks funny because we are trying to express the Celsius temperature in terms of the Fahrenheit temperature and it looks like we have done the opposite. We usually draw our curves $y = f(x)$, that is the $y$-coordinate in terms of $x$. Thus, when we swap the roles of $x$ and $y$, we are preparing ourselves to solve the equation $y = f^{-1}(x)$ for the inverse function. However, this is just semantics, and it doesn't matter what we call $y$ or $x$, so long as we keep track of which coordinate is the abscissa and which is the ordinate.

And if we want to preserve information, we have
$$
C = (5/9)(F - 32).
$$